# Date increase automatically in other Inputfield

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 1 dropdown Box and 2 input fields.

When i chose a value from the dropdown, (i put the values 12 Month and 60 Month inside) see the picture

[image: Select the number of months]

and when i take with the jquery datepicker a date like '08/11/2012' see the next picture

[image: Select the Date with Datepicker]

Then i want to get automatically in the second inputfield a date with + 12 Month - '08/11/2013' see the picture

[image: Increase the Date automatically from the value of the dropdown]

So when i take a value with 60 Month then it must count + 60 Month like '08/11/2017'

I don't know how to realise that.
All the values comes from a MySQL DB

Here is my code what i have now:

```
    <table id="BLth1B" cellspacing="0" >
         <tr>
          <td id="BLth1" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;JUGEMENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="mySaisie">&nbsp;Régime</td>
          <td id="mySaisie">&nbsp;Date Jugement</td>
          <td id="mySaisie" >&nbsp;Date de Fin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="basic-combo" name="basic-combo">
            <option value="0"></option> 
    <?php

    $QryRegime = "SELECT id_regimes, regimes_ref, mois_reg FROM amep_regimes";
    $ResRegime = mysql_query($QryRegime) OR die(mysql_error());

    while($rowregime = mysql_fetch_assoc($ResRegime)) { 
    echo "<option  value=". $rowregime['id_regimes'] .">" . $rowregime['regimes_ref'] . " - " . $rowregime['mois_reg'] . "&nbsp;</option>";  
    }
    ?>
            </select> 
        </td>
          <td><input class="input20" id="datumanfang" /></td>
          <td><input class="input20"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If somebody can help me please??

THX in advance

Answer (score 0):

first things,ID should always be unique,that's why its called id... so make sure you change the ids of this ...

```
 <td id="mySaisie">&nbsp;Régime</td>
 <td id="mySaisie">&nbsp;Date Jugement</td>
 <td id="mySaisie" >&nbsp;Date de Fin</td>
```

Datepicker has this options. take a look at the documentation.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

and Do something like this...

```
$(function(){
    $('#datumanfang').datepicker({
         onSelect: function(date,obj){
             var selectvalue=$('#basic-combo').val(); // get a select value
             var addeddate=date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + selectvalue); //add that value
             $(#idOfLastInput).datepicker( "setDate", addeddate);  // give and id to the last input... and select that
         }
    });
});
```

And I recommend you to use [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) for date calculation and playing around with date object.

Comment: Hi and sorry for my late response. Thank you for your help. I have tried your code, but i don't get it to work. I found your suggestion about 'date.js' very interesting. If you have an example (on JSfiddle) for me, because on the site i don't understand how to realize that. THX

Comment: ok where are u facing the problem in the code??? and about date js... u jus have to load the js file.. and use its function mentioned in the documentation....